# NGINX Rewrite url not works

Tags: nginx, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I have following location with rewrite:

```
location ~ ^/payment/gateway/v2/order/complete/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://api.test.com:8080/payment/gateway/v2/order/complete?order_id=$1;
}
```

then I tried this:

```
 location /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete {
    rewrite ^/payment/gateway/v2/order/complete/(.+) /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete?order_id=$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api.test.com:8080
}
```

then this:

```
 location /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete/ {
    rewrite ^/payment/gateway/v2/order/complete/$ /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete?order_id=$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://api.test.com:8080
}
```

then this:

```
location /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete {
    rewrite ^/payment/gateway/v2/order/complete/([^/]+)$ /payment/gateway/v2/order/complete?order_id=$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://api.test.com:8080;
}
```

all of them not works.

Nginx version 1.13.8

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
All of code above works fine, I found my mistake. I copied one of configuration file to conf.d folder for backup but forgot rename it extension. I removed it and all works fine. Thank you for all for help!

Comment: did you enable rewrite_mod module for nginx ?

Comment: I thought it is enabled by default, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | tr -- - '\n' | grep  _module
```

This is how to ckeck installed modules. I have the same issue and looks like I don't have the module installed/enabled...